# Listen to EarPod's play/pause button click

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a way to take input from the play/pause button on EarPods?

Is there a key code for it or something?

I could not find any questions that are related to this.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I doubt that this button is detectable from JavaScript in a web browser.